# YA Book trilogy about a girl who turns out to be a troll queen

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I remember that this was a trilogy and that one book cover was red and another was green.

The books talk about this girl who ia retrieved by this sort of knight of a troll court and it turns out that she is the princess that was switched with a human baby.

Her (human) mother always knew that she wasnt her real daughter and tried to kill her, thus she got locked up on a mental instituton.

When the protagonist is returned to her wold she starts to learn to control her magic, also there was something a war and she was in love with two guys: the knight and a prince i think, she end up with the prince

Answer (score 5):

The Trylle trilogy by Amanda Hocking. From [Amazon's description](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Trylle-Switched-Torn-Ascend-Novels/dp/1250034906):

> **SWITCHED**
>
> When Wendy Everly was six years old, her mother was convinced she was a monster and tried to kill her. Eleven years later, Wendy discovers she is a changeling who was switched at birth. Now she is about to journey to a magical world she never knew existed, one that's both beautiful and frightening.
>
> **TORN**
>
> Wendy knew her life would never be the same. Now she learns there is more to the story. She shares a closer connection to her Vittra rivals than she ever imagined. With the threat of war looming, her only hope of saving the Trylle is to master her magical powers - and marry an equally powerful royal. Torn between her heart and her people, between love and duty, Wendy must decide her fate.
>
> **ASCEND**
>
> Wendy is facing an impossible choice. The only way to save the Trylle from their deadliest enemy is by sacrificing herself.  If she doesn't surrender to the Vittra, her people will be thrust into a brutal war against an unbeatable foe.  Everything has been leading to this moment.  The future of her entire world rests in her hands.